# What is the most recommended and secure way of storing fingerprints?

Tags: c#, sql-server, storage, fingerprint

I'm working on a .NET Project which involves scanning fingerprints of our clients. We have currently the following methods in mind to store the sensitive data:

- Fingerprint template files (Most likely in Azure) and the file's unique name in our database along with the hash for comparing two fingerprints.
- Store the image directly into our database. (SQL Server)

We will be dealing with about 104,000 unique fingerprints a month for the first few months because it involves general public. Afterwards, it will be just a quick match for the recurring customers. Which one would you prefer and why? I'm open to all other suggestions you've instead of these two methods. Thank you.

Comment: If image is small <1MB VARBINARY, if more FILESTREAM/FILETABLE.

Comment: Storing inside is preffered I think - you always have backup - when you make backup of DB, also the access to the image is more secure - it is not just a file in the DB. You can also encrypt that data.

Comment: What a really interesting question :o) If the fingerprint is used for authentication then it is equivalent to a password and presumably should therefore be hashed before storage...

Comment: @lad2025 We will get our hands on the fingerprint scanner within this week I hope so. Storage is actually not an issue at all. We are just looking for the most secure way.

BogdanBogdanov, Yes, we are currently thinking the same and the backup option you mentioned can be really useful for our project. 

MikeGoodwin, Thank you for pointing that out! I missed that, question updated :)

Comment: to add to @MikeGoodwin comment: indeed you should hash at soon as possible - that is at the client or even at the fingerprint-sensor - the server does not need to know it at all (and should not) - of course you need TLS ...

Comment: how you store biometric data would depend (at an absolute minimum) on the legislation in place in your jurisdiction. After a quick google, my own country's data protection commissioner has the following guidelines for storing employee biometric data (wasn't able to find one for customer biometrics) https://www.dataprotection.ie/docs/Biometrics-in-the-workplace-/244.htm

Comment: @Carsten We don't have any fingerprints at the moment since it's still about two and a half months remaining before the project goes public. Since the data is highly sensitive and large as well, we are just discussing pros and cons of various methods from all aspects before deciding one. Yes, it would be hashed at the client side since it's kinda useless do that on server side. Thank you :)

Comment: @user1666620 That's great but unfortunately we don't have anything like this over here.

Comment: I also ment, @Humza Uthmani, that there are security restrictions to database tables and column. Also encryption options - I mean the storing in DB will be much more secure - not only from backup point of view.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov Obviously yes, that's common sense. it's far more secured than simple file storage anywhere. As for now, database looks more promising for this task.

Comment: One more option, but it will compicate maintenance - you can more table with that info inside additional file group. Because each DB backup will contain fingerprints.

Comment: Azure blob storage is very good from a backup perspective since it it can be automatically georeplicated. From a security point of view, it is somewhat weaker than a SQL DB because you cannot lock down access to specific IP addresses. However, you can do access control and encryption would give you some defence in depth.

Comment: Why are you keeping the images as well as the hashes? If the answer is "I don't know" then it is probably illegal for you to keep them in the European Union - because in the EU you **need** a reason to store sensitive personal data (which this is). Or if you are offering services to anyone in the EU under the EU-US safe-harbour agreement - which requires you to operate to the same standards. Likewise with sensitive data like this the security requirements become an order of magnitude harder to implement and organise.

Comment: (1/2) @Ben I'll explain the whole scenario. This system is being implemented in Pakistan and a large number of pilgrims visit Saudi Arabia every year which are required to perform biometric authentications at the time of their entry. Due to a very large expected rise in the number of pilgrims from all around the world, they're implementing the same system in every country with a significant number of pilgrims visiting every year. However, it's still not sure whether it's going to be implemented this year or not. Once it's clear, we will have a definite mechanism for the exchange of data.

Comment: (2/2) @Ben For now, all we know is that we have to deal with a large number of fingerprints and scanned Iris. That's why we are discussing all possible methods to secure and store them. Until or unless we have clear instructions from the Saudi Embassy about how the exchange of data will take place, it still remains vague in which format we will be storing fingerprints. That's why we are discussing all possible ways and preparing ourselves for any kind of storage method by having sufficient knowledge before we are told to do so.

Comment: Sounds like a challenging project. I assume you will be registering EU pilgrims also. Don't forget to consider the security requirements and legal implications for all of your pilgrims.

Comment: @Ben Yes it is, we got deadlines already and the very same Embassy isn't even making clear how the exchange of data will take place. That's why we are considering all the possible options for all available methods so whatever they decide in the future, we are ready to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Before to know if it's better to store template or image, you have to answer these questions.

You want to store large database of fingerprints, and after try to match a user.

- Where do you want to match current user ? on client-side or on server-side ?
- Do you want to match current user against saved fingerprints ? If yes you want to match current user with all fingerprints (100,000) or just an identified user (between 1 and 10 fingerprints) ?
- What's solution/technology you used to match fingerprint ?

**UPDATE1**

Matching fingerprints it's not just match hash of template or image. Please read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition.

You need a specific algorithm to match fingerprints, for server if you need to match a fingerprints against a database of fingerprints, there's AFIS solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification.

So "How to store fingerprints" depends on AFIS requirements.

Comment: 1.  We will match the users on server-side.
2. We are thinking of comparing the hash with the one already saved with us.
3. We do not have any technology for now scanning / matching fingerprints. We will get our hands on the fingerprint scanners in this week hopefully. Exchange of data will take place between us and another company and they hadn't made it clear as of yet how it will happen. That's why we are considering all the possible options for all available methods. I wrote two detailed comments under the main question, you will like to read them.

Comment: @HumzaUthmani Is it useful ?